# How can i change Policy Modes from Exclude mode to Include mode in cloudflare warp-cli?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, cloudflare

I'm using Linux server. How can I switch from Exclude mode to Include mode in warp-cli? If this functionality isn't available in warp-cli, can I accomplish this using iptables?